# Samesite=Strict for PHP cookie doesn't work

Tags: php, cookies

When I'm setting a cookie in PHP I can't get the cookie with the value samesite=Strict.
Without the parameter samesite the cookie is set, but as soon as I add the parameter samesite to setcookie the cookie isn't set.

The php version I'm using is 7.4.3

```
setcookie('login', ''.$nonce.'', strtotime('NOW+1DAYS'), "/", "", "true", "true", "Strict");
```

Does anyone know why this isn't working?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php - You're passing in 8 arguments (the last being `Strict`), but that function only has 7 arguments. Try using the `setcookie(string $name, string $value = "", array $options = []): bool` way of setting the cookie instead and pass `'samesite' => 'Strict'` in the option array instead (you can see some examples of this in the comments in the manual)

Comment: Thanks! I tried that before. I can set the cookie to Lax, but Strict doesn't work. When I use the value Strict it is set to none